# AzureML to use geo-replication / secondary Blob Storage container for Datastore

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-machine-learning-service, geo-replication

For sake of safety I wish to use geo-replication / secondary Blob Storage container for a data source for AzureML Datastore. So I do the following:

1. New Datastore
2. Enter name + Azure Blob Storage + Enter manually
3. For URL I paste "Secondary Blob Service Endpoint" value from "Storage account endpoints" and I add container name at the end, e.g. https://somedata-secondary.blob.core.windows.net/container-name
4. Select subscription ID
5. I select the resource group in which somedata is hosted,
6. I add account key taken from "Access keys" section, I tried also with SAS token
7. After finalizing, the new datastore seem to appear in the list but it is impossible to Browse (preview), throwing the error "Invalid host".

What is the correct way of doing this?
Is it possible at all to access this geo-replication / secondary Blob Storage as datastore?

Answer (score 1):

Please check with below points:

Initially please check  if Share Access Token (SAS) token is outdated or expired

Please note that Both primary and geo-secondary are required to have the **same service tier** and strongly recommended that the geo-secondary is configured with the same backup storage redundancy and compute size  as the primary.

***Note:** You can only access your storage account by its primary name. In the event of failover, that name will be mapped to the alternate datacenter.*

> There are two disadvantages of GRS redundancy:
>
> - Replication between regions is asynchronous and so data is propagated    with a small delay
> - The second region cannot be accessed or read until the storage    account fails over

[Active geo-replication - Azure SQL Database | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/active-geo-replication-overview#configuring-secondary-database)

As the replicated endpoint will be https://account-secondary.blob.core.windows.net. **Note that this DNS entry won’t even be registered unless read access geo redundant replication is enabled.**

The access keys for your storage account are the same for both the primary and secondary endpoints. You can use the same primary (or secondary) access key for the secondary too.

Comment: I checked those remarks, but the problem is still not fixed. I use Read-access geo-redundant storage so reading shall be possible. After I get definitive response from Microsoft support, I will update the thread.